# From where does re, res come in express

Tags: node.js, express

I was following some tutorial related to express.

There the author made a middleware

```
function authCheck (req, res, next) {
  if (req.user) next() 
  else res.redirect("/somepath")
}
```

and then in API route he used it like this

```
router.get("/emailfetch", authCheck, async (req, res) => {

})
```

**Questions**

So I have three questions.

**1st** Our `authCheck` function is taking three things

```
  function authCheck (req, res, next) {
```

and I don't see we passing them when calling it inside our get route middleware so how does it get `req, res, next`

**2nd.** Suppose I make a helper function file **helper.js** , will our helper.js have access to `req,res,next`?

**3rd** why isn't he doing **authCheck()**, rather why is he just doing **authCheck**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 . `function authCheck (req, res, next)` : is middleware

here

- **req** is for request object ,
- **res** is for response object ,
- **next** is middleware function in the application’s request-response cycle , it passes control to next block

read more about [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)

express provide syntax for passing middleware like below :

```
route.get('/your_route',yourMiddlewareFuntion,function(req,res){

});
```

so your middleware function has access to `request` and `response` object.

2 . Yes , you can create custom middleware in separate file and use it in your route.

example : your `helper.js` is like :

```
module.exports = function(req,res,next){
   // middleware logic goes here 
   // like check users is logged in or not 
  if(req.user){ 
     // user is logged in so able to access private route like dashboard
     next();
  }else{
     // redirect user to login page
     return res.redirect('/login');
  }
}
```

so now you define route like

```
var checkAuth=require('./helper');

route.get('/dashboard',checkAuth,function(req,res){
    // user is logged in , find some data and display it 
    return res.render('/dashboard');
});
```

> when you hit this route /dashboard in your browser , the request will
>   first go through checkAuth middleware , it checks you are loggedin or
>   not , if you are not logged in you will be redirected to login page ,
>   else your request pass to next block , that is function in your
>   /dashboard route , that , will fetch custom data and display it on
>   dashboard.

3 . in above example , we used middleware function by require it and assign it to `checkAuth` variable so that's why we have use `checkAuth` not `checkAuth()`

or you can direct use `function(req,res,next){}` in your route as middleware

Answer (score 1):

1) Express uses the `next` function to move to the next middleware in the chain. By default, the same `req`, `res` and `next` parameters are passed to each middleware therefore you can simply call `next()` rather than explicitly passing the parameters via `next(req, res, next)`. It's very rare you would need to override these parameters but the mechanism exists for those types of scenarios.

2) As long as `helper.js` is passed as middleware, then yes.

3) Middleware must be passed as a function ref because Express then invokes it internally. Scenarios where you have perhaps seen middleware called like `func()` would be where it internally returns a function that matches the Express middleware signature e.g.

```
function middleware() {
  return (req, res, next) => {
     ...
  }
}
...
router.get("/path", middleware(), ...
```

On its own this type of approach is of no value, however it can be useful in scenarios where you want to pass additional information to your middleware rather than relying on globals, which helps with testing.